# How to Create ConnectionPool In A Normal Java Program

Tags: java, jdbc

I am developing a normal java program which may require to use 100s of DB connections. Please note that this program will not run on any server. We run this program just like below.

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

So I need to create a connection pool in my program. I did a lot of research regarding this. I found a lot of posts, in these post people created connection pools like its a normal list. They manually created connections and populated into the list. I don't think it's a good Idea.

Is there any better way to create a connection pool in a normal Java program, which does not run on any server.

your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should have a look at the following article

https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071834/build-ci-sdlc/pool-resources-using-apache-s-commons-pool-framework.html

It describes how to use the Apache Commons Pool Framework. As far as I know you can use this framework in a normal Java Program.